# How to check participants in at events?

Tags: civievent

How would you recommend checking in participants (who have previously registered) at events so that those who attended have participant status changed from registered to attended? (And then, likely in a second step, those who didn't show have participant status changed to no-show). This seems so obvious- but I can't find it in the Civi documentation.

My thought is to use an advanced search with event name= [name], role = 'attendee' filters. After people have been checked off names when they come in to the event, use the 'update multiple contacts' feature. I created a profile with the field 'participant status', but it doesn't show up in the 'update multiple contacts' profile drop-down...and I'm wondering if this is even the best way to do this? Non-developer, just a user here. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Drupal you can build a View and use VBO and then have a list of all Participants, and a checkbox, then you just tick them off, and then when the evening is complete, submit the form and change the Participant Status to Attended - if you are using Drupal I will add this as an Answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CiviLearner,

You will need to use Find Participant search form to update the status of participant.

Do a search on event name= [name], role = 'attendee' filters, select participant and then from Actions list select 'Update multiple participant'

Or You can use Advance search with same filter but select 'Event Participants' from the 'Display Results As'.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 4):

If you use Advanced Search, you can change the *Display Results As* from **Contacts** to **Participants**.  This will let you update the participant status similarly to doing it through "Manage Events", but with more granularity for who shows up in your list.

You can also install [CiviMobile](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile) - the Web Access CiviMobile, not Agiliway's - which has a one-touch phone interface I really like for changing folks from "Registered" to "Attended".  Afterward, I use the method I mention above to convert non-attendees to no-shows.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't (yet) tried it but have bookmarked the [QR Code Checkin extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin), which could be used in conjunction with one of the other described "backup" methods for those who didn't take their QR code with them to the event:

> QRCode Checkin allows you to send an email that contains a scanable code to the registered participants for your event.
>
> Your registration workers can use any freely available QR Code scanning software on their phones to scan the code and open the encoded web address on their browser.
>
> When they do, they will get the status information about the registration
>
> With one click, the registration worker can change their status from registered to attended.

Answer (score 1):

Answer I got (other suggestions welcomed):

```
Navigate to Events > Manage Events
```

Scroll to find the event in question, click on the Participants hyperlink to the right-hand side, then select "Connected, Registered, Attended..."

Select resulting participants, then select "Participant status - change" from the actions drop down menu >